# How can I tell if Cross domain tracking is working properly with GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have the following Custom HTML tag setup in Google Tag Manager (note: I know you can create an Universal Analytics tag type, however, because of the setup, I have to use a Custom HTML Tag Type).

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', {{uaid}}, 'auto', {
  'allowLinker': true
});

// Load the plugin.
ga('require', 'linker');

// Define which domains to autoLink.
ga('linker:autoLink', [{{cross domains}}]);

// enhanced link attribution
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');

// send
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Where `{{uaid}}` is my universal analytics tracking number and `{{ cross domains }}` is a list of the domains I'm trying to properly track - i.e. ['mydomain.com','seconddomain.com','thirddomain.com].

I have have `sub.mydomain.com` that I'm trying to track as well. Will the `mydomain.com` in the above `{{ cross domains }}` list take all subdomains into account?

Basically, **I've set all this up through Google's documentation. How can I ensure it's working properly?**

Answer (score 6):

The code you posted looks okay, assuming you didn't typo your domain names, etc..

Yes, specifying `mydomain.com` should cover all subdomains e.g. `foobar.mydomain.com`.

To test it, go to a page on one of the domains that links to another one of the domains.

**NOTE:** pick one that goes to a different root domain. Going from `mydomain.com` to `foobar.mydomain.com` won't help you test this because the cookie is set on the root domain and nothing special is invoked.

Use your favorite tool to look at the request being made to GA. For example use the browser's developer tools > net tab.

Request URL starts like this:

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?...
```

In the url you should see a `cid` param that looks something like this:

```
cid=1885489529.1395091795
```

This is the client id (visitor id).  Now, click on a link on the page that goes to another domain in your list. You should see that the target page should have a `_ga` parameter appended to it, something like this:

```
_ga=1.241257986.1885489529.1395091795
```

And in the `www.google-analytics.com` request on the target page, you should see the same `cid` param that you saw on the first page.

```
cid=1885489529.1395091795
```

If the `cid` for the original page and the target page match up, that means the page view is using the same client/visitor id and will count as the same visit(or) in the reports.

**NOTE:** The `cid` and `_ga` values are visitor unique so you should see a value in that format but not those exact numbers.

**NOTE:** GA's cross-domain tracking basically only works for standard links that don't have any other kind of trickery happening.  For example if you have links generated after your GA code is run, this won't work. Or if you have non-standard exit links (e.g. links that go to some controller page and ultimately redirect to target site, or links with no href that use javascript to ultimately redirect) then this won't work. For links such as these, you will need to [follow the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) for calling the GA method to get that `_ga` param and use your own means to append it to the URL.